# Mock put requests with mock-axios-adapter

Tags: vue.js, mocking, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I have simple Vue component that fetches API key when it is created and key can be renewed by clicking on button:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>{{data.api_key}}</div>
        <button ref="refresh-trigger" @click="refreshKey()">refresh</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        created() {
            axios.get(this.url).then((response) => {
                this.data = response.data
            })
        }
        methods: {
            refreshKey() {
                axios.put(this.url).then((response) => {
                    this.data = response.data
                })
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

And I want to test it with this code:

```
import {shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils';
import axios from 'axios';
import apiPage from '../apiPage';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';



describe('API page', () => {
    it('should renew API key it on refresh', async (done) => {
        const flushPromises = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve))
        const initialData = {
            api_key: 'initial_API_key',
        };
        const newData = {
            api_key: 'new_API_key',
        };
        const mockAxios = new MockAdapter(axios);

        mockAxios.onGet('/someurl.json').replyOnce(200, initialData)
        mockAxios.onPut('/someurl.json').replyOnce(200, newData);

        const wrapper = shallowMount(api);
        expect(wrapper.vm.$data.data.api_key).toBeFalsy();

        await flushPromises()

        wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
            expect(wrapper.vm.$data.data.api_key).toEqual(initialData.api_key);
            done()
        });

        wrapper.find({ref: 'refresh-trigger'}).trigger('click');

        wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
            console.log(mockAxios.history)

            expect(wrapper.vm.$data.data.api_key).toEqual(newData.api_key);

            expect(mockAxios.history.get.length).toBe(1);
            expect(mockAxios.history.get[1].data).toBe(JSON.stringify(initialData));

            expect(mockAxios.history.put.length).toBe(1);
            done();
        });
    })
});
```

But it turns out only get request is mocked because i receive:

```
        [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Difference:

    - Expected
    + Received

    - new_API_key
    + initial_API_key"

found in

---> <Anonymous>
<Root>

console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1883
{ Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected)
```

Even worse, `console.log(mockAxios.history)` returns empty put array:

```
{ get:
   [ { transformRequest: [Object],
       transformResponse: [Object],
       timeout: 0,
       xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
       xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
       maxContentLength: -1,
       validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
       headers: [Object],
       method: 'get',
       url: '/admin/options/api.json',
       data: undefined } ],
  post: [],
  head: [],
  delete: [],
  patch: [],
  put: [],
  options: [],
  list: [] }
```

I tried to define mockAxios in describe block, and console.log it after iteration - and it turns out that put request was here. But not when I needed it. :)

What am i doing wrong? Maybe there are some ways to check if created callback was called and all async functions inside it are done? Maybe i'm using axios-mock wrong?

Comment: Why you mocking after the call shallowMount?

Comment: looks like a typo, thanks. anyway, it doesn't fix issue

Answer (score 0):

This test code should pass:

```
import {shallowMount, createLocalVue} from '@vue/test-utils';
import axios from 'axios';
import api from '@/components/api.vue';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
describe('API page', () => {
    it('should renew API key it on refresh', async () => {
        const flushPromises = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve))
        const initialData = {
            api_key: 'initial_API_key',
        };
        const newData = {
            api_key: 'new_API_key',
        };
        const mockAxios = new MockAdapter(axios);
        const localVue = createLocalVue();
        mockAxios
          .onGet('/someurl.json').reply(200, initialData)
          .onPut('/someurl.json').reply(200, newData);

        const wrapper = shallowMount(api, {
          localVue,
        });
        expect(wrapper.vm.$data.data.api_key).toBeFalsy();

        await flushPromises();
        expect(wrapper.vm.$data.data.api_key).toEqual(initialData.api_key);
        wrapper.find({ref: 'refresh-trigger'}).trigger('click');
        await flushPromises();
        console.log(mockAxios.history);
        expect(wrapper.vm.$data.data.api_key).toEqual(newData.api_key);

        expect(mockAxios.history.get.length).toBe(1);
        expect(mockAxios.history.put.length).toBe(1);

    })
});
```

A few notes:

1. I prefer to chain the responses on the mockAxios object, that way you can group them by URL so it's clear which endpoint you're mocking:

```
mockAxios
  .onGet('/someurl.json').reply(200, initialData)
  .onPut('/someurl.json').reply(200, newData);

mockAxios
  .onGet('/anotherUrl.json').reply(200, initialData)
  .onPut('/anotherUrl.json').reply(200, newData);
```

2. If you want to test that you only made one GET call to the endpoint (with `expect(......get.length).toBe(1)`) then you should really use `reply()` instead of `replyOnce()` and test it the way you're doing it already. The `replyOnce()` function will remove the handler after replying first time and you'll be getting 404s in your subsequent requests.
3. `mockAxios.history.get[1].data` will not contain anything for 3 reasons: GET requests don't have a body (only URL parameters), you only made 1 GET request (here you're checking 2nd GET), and this statement refers to the request that was sent, not data you received.
4. You're using `async/await` feature, which means you can take advantage of that for $nextTick: `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();` and drop the `done()` call all together, but since you already have `flushPromises()` you might as well use that.
5. You don't need to test that you received initialData in the 1st call with this line: 
   `expect(mockAxios.history.get[1].data).toBe(JSON.stringify(initialData));` since you're already testing it with `expect(...).toEqual(apiKey)`.
6. Use `createLocalVue()` utility to create a local instance of Vue for each mount to [avoid contaminating](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/common-tips.html#applying-global-plugins-and-mixins) the global Vue instance (useful if you have multiple test groups)

and finally, 7. it's best to break this test up into multiple `it` statements; unit tests should be *micro*tests, i.e. test a small, clearly identifiable behaviour. Although I didn't break the test up for you so it contains as little changes as possible, I'd highly recommend doing it.